# How to implement Foursquare's "Mayor" feature - find the user with the highest score in the last N days?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate, foursquare, leaderboard

In Foursquare, the user who has the highest score for a place in the last N days is awarded the Mayorship of that place.

What is the most efficient way to implement that?

A user could have checked into hundreds of places. To display all the mayorships that belong to a user, it'd be necessary to go through all those hundreds of places one by one and check if he has the highest score in the last 60 days for each place-- that sounds very inefficient.

Is there any SQL or algorithmic magic that could perform the task quickly?

UPDATE: I'm using MySQL and Django

Comment: Need to provide table(s) and their column(s) for those of us not familiar with the game...  Sounds easy, just need to know if there's anything special about score tabulation.  Also, do you (and how do you) break ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the 'current major' in the place table, and update that from time to time. Example (I have no idea if the data model is correct):

```
drop table place;
create table place(name varchar(20) primary key, major varchar(20));
insert into place values('NY', null), ('LA', null);
create index idx_p_m on place(major);

drop table visits;
create table visits(user varchar(20), place varchar(20), points int, day int);
create index idx_v_p on visits(place, day desc);
insert into visits values
  ('Ben', 'NY', 1, 100), 
  ('Ben', 'LA', 3, 102), 
  ('Joe', 'NY', 2, 103), 
  ('Joe', 'LA', 1, 104);

-- just to prove this is efficient  
explain  select user from visits v where v.place = 'NY' 
  and day > 90
  group by user 
  order by sum(points) desc 
  limit 1;

update place p set major = 
  (select user from visits v where p.name = v.place 
  and day > 90
  group by user 
  order by sum(points) desc 
  limit 1);

select * from place where major = 'Joe';
select * from place where name = 'LA';
```

Comment: I forgot to break ties. I guess you need some additional logic, for example order by sum(points) desc, user_joined (assuming old users always win)